# 3.5mm earphone media keys on Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, media-keys, 3.5mm

I have Sennheiser CX 5.00G earphones (the Android version) which I use for my daily music purposes.
Is there any way to make Windows 10 grab the button presses and parse them as media keys?

I'm totally fine with having to find/write/fidget with 3rd party software or even having to write my own C# application to do this if the driver supports it and there is a way to hook into it.

Comment: so, You want to plug it into your PC and make the buttons give orders to your PC?

Comment: @Divin3 Yes, that is what I want, pretty much the way it works on my Nexus 6

Comment: There are different standards for the keys, if the standards arent the same, they wont work.

Comment: This requires your hardware to support the 4 pins. If your headphone jack on your computer does not have 4 contacts inside it, it will be impossible for this to work without purchasing additional hardware. But, if your computer DOES have the 4 contacts inside the audio jack, it should work automatically. Make sure your audio drivers are up to date.

Answer (score -1):

Some newer laptops can detect the 4 pin jack by default. I know that on MacBooks, this feature does work.

If You have a microphone input on your PC, than You can get this working with an Y adapter like this:
[image]

This will convert the 4 pin jack of your headset into two 3 pin jacks.

Just google `Smartphone Headset to PC Adapter`

Comment: I have one of those adapters but that doesn't do what I want. I have a microphone that works perfectly fine and so do my earphones, but i want to be able to use the buttons on the earphones as media keys. Guess that just confirms it isn't possible.

Comment: @Ieuan - I am not quite sure it is impossible. It is just a matter of drivers.